# Groovy shell script with a sed command in a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, packer, jenkins-groovy

So writing Groovy with basic shell scripts seem to be much more difficult than it really should be.

I have a pipeline that needs to replace an entry in a file after running a packer command. It seems sensible to do this in the same shell script as the packer command as the variables are not available outside of the shell script even when exported.

The problem is that the sed command needs escape upon escape and still doesn't work. So this is what the Jenkins Pipeline Syntax generator suggested:

```
parallel (
    "build my-application" : {
        sh '''#!/bin/bash
        export PATH=$PATH:~/bin

        cd ${WORKSPACE}/platform/packer
        packer build -machine-readable template.json | tee packer.out
        AMI_APP=$(grep amazon-ebs,artifact,0,id,eu-west-2:ami- packer.out | awk -F: \'{ print $NF }\')
        [[ ! ${AMI_APP} ]] && exit 1

        sed -i.bak \'s!aws_ami_app = \\".*\\"!aws_ami_app = \\"\'"${AMI_APP}"\'\\"!\' ${WORKSPACE}/platform/terraform/env-${ENV}/env.auto.tfvars
        '''
    },
    "build some-more-apps" : {
        sh ''' *** same again different name ***
        '''
    }
)
```

What is the correct way to get a variable is a sed command working in a bash script running in groovy?

Any tips for the correct syntax going forward with Jenkins, groovy and bash - any documentation that actually helps?

EDIT

The original sed command that is running in a Jenkins Job shell is:

```
sed -i.bak 's!aws_ami_app = \".*\"!aws_ami_app = \"'"${AMI_APP}"'\"!' ${WORKSPACE}/platform/terraform/env-${ENV}/env.auto.tfvars
```

Comment: Can you post the original sed command which is working when not running in Jenkins?

Comment: It would be easier to save the script into a file and run it instead of fiddling with all the required escaping: you can either run the script from your workspace using `sh './your-script.sh'`.
If you prefer to keep your script within the pipeline I think you only need to escape `$PATH` and `$NF` (assuming the other variables are pipeline parameters).

Comment: If the latest answer from @yong doesn't work, can you please add an example of the line from `env.auto.tfvars` on which you're performing the `sed`? A concrete example of the input might make this a bit easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Please show the content of env.auto.tfvars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you put the shell script inside `'''` which won't trigger [Groovy String interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings).
So you no need to escape any character, write the script as when you typing in Shell cmd window.

Below is example:

```
    sh '''#!/bin/bash +x
    echo "aws_ami_app = docker.xy.com/xy-ap123/conn:7et45u.1.23" > test.txt
    echo "cpu = 512" >> test.txt
    cat test.txt

    AMI_APP=docker.xy.com/xy-ap123/conn:7et45u.1.25
    sed -i 's,aws_ami_app.*,aws_ami_app = '"$AMI_APP"',' test.txt
    cat test.txt
    '''
```

Output in jenkins console:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[poc] Running shell script
aws_ami_app = docker.xy.com/xy-ap123/conn:7et45u.1.23
cpu = 512
aws_ami_app = docker.xy.com/xy-ap123/conn:7et45u.1.25
cpu = 512
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand how a simple sed command like your example works but "sed -i 's/cat/${dog}/' test.txt" is where the problem lies. In bash to get this working you need this '"${dog}"' but this breaks in a triple quoted shell script running in "parallel" (my sed actually works in a triple quote shell). The syntax seems to change in "parallel"?

Comment: Use `"` wrapper sed expression, the `"` will expand variables

Comment: Update answer more close your scenario, should work for you now.  If not, please give an example value of `$AMI_APP`